when run Artisan::call('cache:clear') got Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
I am using Artisan::call('cache:clear') to clear the cache after update roles and permission. I already given sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage and sudo chown -R www-data:www-data bootstrap/cache for folders. but run cache clear artisan command i got Failed to open stream: No such file or directory error. i am using linux os and apache server.
file_put_contents(/var/www/spectse.net/storage/framework/cache/data/14/b1/14b1c21890886e6351e48c7d34e61b418ee3b327): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"view":{"view":"/var/www/spectse.net.net/resources/views/components/setting-sidebar.blade.php","data":[]},"userId":7,"exception":"[object] (Spatie\\LaravelIgnition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/var/www/spectse.net.net/storage/framework/cache/data/14/b1/14b1c21890886e6351e48c7d34e61b418ee3b327): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /var/www/spectse.net.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:204)


Seems the question is already answered here.

Try the following:
create these folders under storage/framework:

sessions
views
cache

Now it should work

Already folders have

php artisan key:generate

You can try. It related to folder permission
chmod 755 /var/www/spectse.net/storage/framework/*

